# How to convert panda.series into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert the pandas dataframe mentioned below

```
dateint    client_id      reactions
20190821   heryi-789      [{count=1, name=hp, users=[xyz1]}]
20190821   ywie-234       [{count=1, name=art, users=[abc2]}, 
                           {count=1, name=wck, users=[xyz]}]
20190821   uiwo-238       [{count=6, name=rtf, users=[tst23, ert34, 
                            abc2]}]
```

TO

```
dateint        client_id    count   name    users
20190821       heryi-789    1       hp      xyz1
20190821       ywie-234     1       art     abc2
20190821       ywie-234     1       wck     xyz
20190821       uiwo-238     3       rtf     tst23
20190821       uiwo-238     3       rtf     ert34
20190821       uiwo-238     3       rtf     abc2
```

I tried to convert the "reactions" column value to dict, however "users" values with multiple values are not converting to list

Comment: What is the type of reaction columns? is it string, dict, or json?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['count'] = df['reactions'].apply(lambda x:x['count'])
df['name'] = df['reactions'].apply(lambda x:x['name'])
df['users'] = df['reactions'].apply(lambda x:x['users'])
```

Then use `df['users'].explode()` if you have pandas version greater than .25

Comment: type(df['reactions']) -  pandas.core.series.Series

I think above code will work if the type of this field is dict. Showing error 
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Can you post code to create the demo dataframe? I will then work on it